# Somebody broke Programmers.StackExchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

No questions are coming up. Error, error, basically. Meta works fine, so uh, great...

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the Maintenance at UX.SE right now?

Comment: @JOG you know how things go when user's are involved, I wouldn't put it past them to have hit the wrong database on accident.